# how to use the elements that are dynamically added in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  var panel1 = new Panel() 
            { 
                Size = new Size(500, 200), 
                Location = new Point(10, i), 
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle 
            };
  panel1.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "hi", Location = new Point(10, 20) });
```

Here we can add a button in a panel...but how to use that button..I mean how to handle the response when it was clicked?

Comment: You can use the approaches described in the answers but the best thing would be to learn at least the basics of windows forms so you understand how things are working.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the button, assign it to a variable, set the event handler and then add it to the panel:

```
var button = new Button { Text = "hi", Location = new Point(10, 20) };
button.Click += MyClickHandler;
panel1.Controls.Add(button);
```

Where `MyClickHandler` is your method.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is this:

```
Button sample = new Button();
sample.Name = "btn1";
sample.Text = "hi";
sample.Location = new Point(10, 20);
sample.Click += button1_Click;

panel1.Controls.Add(sample);
```

and define your method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }
```